# Productlist with all possible configurations

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options, products, product-list, price-rules

We are looking for a way to get a list with all possible product configurations per product and its associated price, including delivery. If the same product has a different price or options it has to be registered as a new product.

e.g.

> productName, price, sku, entityId, array(options, optionIds), delivery
>
> Flyer, 1.99, flyer, 1, [[small, 1], [colorful, 2]], normalDelivery
>
> Flyer, 2.99, flyer, 1, [[big, 3], [colorful, 2]], normalDelivery
>
> Flyer, 3.99, flyer, 1, [[small, 1], [colorful, 2]], fastDelivery
>
> Flyer, 4.99, flyer, 1, [[big, 3], [colorful, 2]], fastDelivery

We tried the following code but it doesn’t contain all possible configurations and their associated price like shown in the example above:

```
<?php $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: We are using Magento 1.9.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `getUsedProducts` function, an example code part may look like this:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(%PRODUCT_ID%); 
$childProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getUsedProducts(null,$product);

foreach($childProducts as $child) {
    print_r($child->getWhateveryouwant());
}
```